# candlestickBarChart and a lineChart on the same NVD3.js chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible, and if yes how, to draw a `candlestickBarChart()` and a line on the same chart similar to [this example](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/linePlusBarChart.html).

[Here](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/scatterPlusLineChart.html) the lines are displayed using `slope` and `intercept` properties of the `scatterChart()` data groups, as it seems.

I'd like to overlay a `candlestickBarChart` (as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/candlestickChart.html)) with multiple arbitrary lines on the same chart (as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/lineChart.html)).

Didn't find a way or example of doing that using the [`multiChart()`](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/multiChart.html). Do I need to use a special `type` value for the the `candlestickBarChart` in the data series?

Comment: You'll probably have to build a new model for this. Refer to https://github.com/COzero/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineWithFocusPlusSecondaryChart.js where I combined lineChart with a secondary chart above.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try.